# Cannot make vim support python

Tags: python, vim

I installed vim in CentOS 6.3.
It has python 2.6 by default, and it is under `/usr/lib`.
When I try to install vim following this link:
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source

It doesn't support both python and python 3.

Because it seemed like the page link assumes you have python 2.7, I downloaded python 2.7. Still no success.

I ran `yum install python-devel`. Still no success.

But also, I noticed that when I call:

```
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim74
```

I get:

> link.sh: $LINK_AS_NEEDED set to 'yes': invoking linker directly.
>     gcc   -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed   -o vim objects/buffer.o objects/blowfish.o objects/charset.o objects/crypt.o objects/crypt_zip.o objects/diff.o objects/digraph.o objects/edit.o objects/eval.o objects/ex_cmds.o objects/ex_cmds2.o objects/ex_docmd.o objects/ex_eval.o objects/ex_getln.o objects/fileio.o objects/fold.o objects/getchar.o objects/hardcopy.o objects/hashtab.o  objects/if_cscope.o objects/if_xcmdsrv.o objects/mark.o objects/memline.o objects/menu.o objects/message.o objects/misc1.o objects/misc2.o objects/move.o objects/mbyte.o objects/normal.o objects/ops.o objects/option.o objects/os_unix.o objects/pathdef.o objects/popupmnu.o objects/quickfix.o objects/regexp.o objects/screen.o objects/search.o objects/sha256.o objects/spell.o objects/syntax.o objects/tag.o objects/term.o objects/ui.o objects/undo.o objects/version.o objects/window.o  objects/if_lua.o  objects/if_perl.o objects/if_perlsfio.o objects/if_python.o   objects/if_ruby.o   objects/netbeans.o objects/channel.o  objects/json.o objects/main.o objects/memfile.o        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux   -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -L/usr/lib64/python2.6/config -lpython2.6 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic   -lruby -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm

It seemed to look into `/usr/lib64/python2.6`, not `/usr/lib/python2.6`. So just in case, I created a symlink to `/usr/lib64/python2.6` and `/usr/lib64/python2.7`. Still no success.

Where should I go from here?

Comment: Compiling vim from source seems to be an overkill. In CentOS the package vi is installed by default, what you're looking for is probably *vim-enhanced*.

Comment: Bye the way what do you mean with vim "support" Python? Syntax highlight?

Comment: @jotrocken No + in front of python when I call "vim --version"

Comment: AFAIK the support indicated by + just allows you to run the python interpreter from within vim as `:python <sys.args>`. Not sure if that is worth the compilation hassle. In my Ubuntu I don't have the + either, but syntax highlight works just fine. To run a python command, just use `Ctrl+Z`, run the command and `fg` to come back later, or declare an alias in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Otherwise, what were the arguments you passed to `./configure`? Make sure to have `--enable-pythoninterp` and `--with-python-config-dir` with correct arguments.

Comment: Yeah configured as the link told me to, which had both of those

Comment: So you can have syntax highlight without the python interpreter? Hmmm then I wonder why it doesn't work for me

Comment: Some wild guesses: Did you turn `:syntax on`, [see here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-or-off-color-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-or-vim/)? If that helps, you probably want to put it in your [.vimrc](http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.html). Does your terminal support colored output at all? Did you start `vim` and not `vi`? Did you try this with the packaged version of vim?

Comment: "Error detected while processing /etc/vimrc:

line   50:

E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim"

That's my message when I launch vim. And no I don't have anything in the vim74 folder. So I guess I should add the syntax.vim file. I tried looking for it already, but I can't find the default syntax file online

Comment: It looks as if the installation is incomplete. This file should be included in the packaged version of vim. Try a clean install `yum install vim-X11 vim-common vim-enhanced vim-minimal` ([source](http://apetec.com/linux/InstallVIM.htm))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compile vim yourself to get syntax highlight.

From what we found out in the comments, it looks as if your installation is incomplete. To get Python syntax highlight in vim, try a clean installation via the package manager of CentOS:

```
yum install vim-X11 vim-common vim-enhanced vim-minimal
```

Then enable syntax highlight by either typing `:syntax on` inside vim or adding the following line to the file `.vimrc` in your home directory (the latter makes it permanent):

```
syntax on
```

See [this page](http://apetec.com/linux/InstallVIM.htm) for an example `.vimrc`.

Comment: Since I failed to install vim with syntax highlight from source, I have already tried downloading that way. Currently version is yum installed version. However, I get

"Error detected while processing /etc/vimrc: line 50: E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim"

Comment: If I call that I get "Setting up Install Process
Package 2:vim-X11-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version             
Package 2:vim-common-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version              
Package 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version              
Package 2:vim-minimal-7.4.629-5.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version            
Nothing to do"

So it is indeed installed

Comment: Strange. 1) According to [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos) CentOS 6.3 comes with a vim version less than 7.4. Try to remove what is left of your self-compiled installation, then try again. 2) Try `yum reinstall [...]` instead of install. 3) Maybe the file is in a different location: Do a `find /usr/ -name "syntax.vim"` and create a symlink to the result with `ln -s [result of find] /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim`. The latter command requires root access and maybe you have to create the directory first with `mkdir -p /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/`.

Comment: I've already done a find to look for syntax.vim. It doesn't exist. And vim version is 7.4.629. Somehow it thinks vim is full installed despite missing syntax folder. Anyway, I actually solved it by transferring all the syntax files from a working vim, and it seems to be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is caused by the legacy files in the last build.

Everything works well after I clean these files.

```
make distclean

./configure *** (parameters) ***

make

make install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vim to edit, but having difficulty running the file afterwards by doing "$ python foobar.py", then you probably want to specify the python version at the top of the file as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```